# Get Database size Java(JPA)

Tags: java, jpa

I already know that a plain SQL query like the following will return the size of `my_db`  in megabytes.

```
SELECT SUM(data_length + index_length ) /1024 /1024 FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'my_db' GROUP BY table_schema"
```

although I haven't been able to execute this in a Java context, nor I have found its equivalent in `JPA`.

Is there any way to get a databases size without using native sql like I am trying?

I tried the following, but I get exception related to sql syntax.

```
public Long dbSize(){
    TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT SUM(data_length + index_length ) /1024 /1024 FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'my_db' GROUP BY table_schema" , Long.class);
    long size = query.getSingleResult();
    return size;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help/suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `em.createNativeQuery()`, that's what should be used for plain SQL queries.

Comment: I don't think you'll find any JPA support for this, but good luck. Being database vendor - specific as it is, I think it would have to be implemented in dialect classes, and I don't recall seeing anything related there. In my opinion, native query solution is just fine here.